# Wakanda: how to change class of a custom widget on attribute change?

Tags: javascript, class, wakanda

I'm creating a custom widget in Wakanda.

This widget must change a class in function of a property. For example, if the property shadowDepth=2 then I will set the class as `mdl-shadow--2dp`, else if shadowDepth=6 I will set the class as mdl-shadow--6dp.

How could I change the class this way?

Answer (score 0):

The most used approach is the following:

1. Add an `enum` attribute to the custom Widget.
2. Consider the existing class at Widget initialisation.
3. Make an `onChange` trigger to apply your desired classes.

Let's view each step separately:

#### 1. Add an enum custom attribute

I expect you know how to create a custom widget. Let's add the attribute to the widget definition in `widget.js`:

```
var myWidget = widget.create('myWidget', {
  // widget attributes
});
```

for an `enum` attribute you can define it as it follows:

```
shadowDepth: widget.property({
  type: 'enum',
  description: 'Shadow depth for MDL widget',
  values: {
    'mdl-shadow--1dp': '1',
    'mdl-shadow--2dp': '2',
    'mdl-shadow--3dp': '3',
    'mdl-shadow--4dp': '4',
    'mdl-shadow--5dp': '5',
    'mdl-shadow--6dp': '6'
  },
  defaultValue: 'mdl-shadow--2dp',
  bindable: false
})
```

This way you have added your `enum` attribute which does nothing for the moment.

#### 2. If the widget has already one of the classes, set the property attribute value (initialValue)

In order to retrieve the initial value of the widget, which can be assigned in the DOM, we define the `defaultValueCallback` function as it follows in the attribute property just after `defaultValue`:

```
  defaultValueCallback: function() {
    var r = /mdl-shadow--\ddp/.exec(this.node.className); // regex are cool
    return r[r.length - 1] || 'mdl-shadow--2dp'; // return the latest occurrence of the class or the default value
  },
```

#### 3. the onChange trigger

In the `init` attribute declaration of the widget add the following code:

```
init: function() {
  // first call to set the attribute
  this._changeShadowDepth(this.shadowDepth());
  // onChange event
  this.shadowDepth.onChange(this._changeShadowDepth);
}
```

and add the `_changeShadowDepth` function as it follows:

```
_changeShadowDepth: function(value) {
  var $node = $(this.node); // jQuery is included in the prototype, do not worry
  [
    'mdl-shadow--1dp', 'mdl-shadow--2dp', 'mdl-shadow--3dp',
    'mdl-shadow--4dp', 'mdl-shadow--5dp', 'mdl-shadow--6dp'
  ].forEach(function(klass) {
    $node.removeClass(klass);
  });
  if (value) {
    $node.addClass(value);
  }
},
```

This is the same exact approach used by the official [Image widget](https://github.com/Wakanda/Image/tree/WAK11) to change the align (background-align) property.